# Interactive mosaic-like gallery with jquery

Tags: jquery, flash, gallery, interactive

I've been tasked with recreating the Flash portion of this site in html/java/css:
http://clairchoidesign.site90.net/embrace.html

I'm fairly new at javascript but I know a good amount of html and css.

Trying to figure out where to start. As you can tell from the flash section, this isn't a standard gallery or slider setup. The nav is overlayed on top of the slideshow and has rollover states.

I've attempted messing around with idTabs: http://www.sunsean.com/idTabs/

But I'm not sure how to overlay the nav controls on top of the content. Plus it wouldn't provide a decent image transition.

It seems like this would be possible to recreate in a non-flash environment, I'm just not sure where to start.

If anyone could point me in the right direction here I would really appreciate it.
Thanks!

Comment: what code did you write so far ?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't even figured out where to start. I usually try and find some sort of existing solution then adapt it as necessary.

Comment: I found a good place to start: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/07/03/sliding-background-image-menu/ I would need to somehow get multiple rows of buttons. Going to mess around with the css to see if I can..

Answer (score 0):

[Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) is a jQuery plugin that seems like it might be able to do that. At the very least, it would be a good place to start, to learn how to accomplish effects like that in HTML/CSS/jQuery.